# sql server select percent from table and all data from another table

Tags: c#, sql-server

i have two tables (families) and (children ) that related by family id ... every family has more than one child .. i use percentage to select families from families table and i want to know count of children to each family selected ... but   when i use percentage the program return children count by percentage ... so how can i select percentage from families and all children that related to families ... my query is

```
select count(*) Children from 
    (select top('" + int.Parse(percentCb2.Text) + "') percent 
     f.family_id ,
     f.economic_state 
     from families f inner join Children c on c.family_id = f.family_id 
     where f.economic_state = 'b')fq 
     group by fq.family_id
```

Comment: I'm not quite following what output you are getting vs. what output you want. can you post an example?

Comment: when i select 50 percent of families and get count of children that relate to to selected family ... the count of children also use the percent .. if family has 4 children ... the query return just 2 children ... i want select 50 percent of families and get count of all children that belong to selected families

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to take the top families, and THEN do the join

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Children 
FROM
    (SELECT top('" + int.Parse(percentCb2.Text) + "') percent 
     f.family_id ,
     f.economic_state 
     FROM families
     WHERE f.economic_state = 'b') f
INNER JOIN Children c on c.family_id = f.family_id 
GROUP BY fq.family_id
```

Comment: hello again dagarrison ... one another thing .. how can i make percent 5 when percent was more than 4.5 .. and 4 when percent was smaller than 4.5

Comment: I suspect you should be able to use http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx

Comment: @user3038625 Assuming that you're building the query string in C#, try using `Math.Round(double.Parse(percentCb2.Text), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`.